# ASP.NET Custom Profile serializeAs Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, profile

I am trying to implement a custom profile class in C# that inherits System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase. I have a few properties of type System.Collections.Generic.List that need to be serialized as binary instead of the default XML. However, I am unsure of how to mark that setting in Profile class.

For instance, I have a property named "SavedReports" that is of type List. If I were to use the web.config approach, i would simply write :

```
<code>
<profile>
 <providers>
  <add name="SavedReports" serializeAs="Binary" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.SavedReports]"/>
<code>
```

However, I am unsure how I would add the serializeAs="Binary" attribute in C# for the custom implementation:

`[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]`

```
    public List<SavedReport> SavedReports
    {
        get { return base["SavedReports"] as List<SavedReport>; }
        set { base["SavedReport"] = value; }
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found this:

[SettingsSerializeAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeasattribute.aspx)

> With the SettingsSerializeAsAttribute,
>   you can specify which serialization
>   mechanism should be used for a given
>   application settings class or
>   property. This attribute is considered
>   a request to the settings provider. It
>   may be ignored or cause an error if
>   the provider or the individual
>   property type does not support the
>   specified serialization scheme. If
>   this attribute is not present, the
>   provider will usually provide a
>   default serialization mechanism, most
>   commonly plain text.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Daniel!

I added a System.Configuration reference and added [SettingsSerializeAsAttribute(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)] to the declaration.


Thanks Again!